# why the localhost page isn’t working in lampp (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to run my cakephp project in LAMP. My LAMP is already running phpmyadmin and it is also working well for another project. When I search http://localhost/mobishop/ then it works only home page. If I go to my panel with http://localhost/mobishop/mobiadmin it does not work and shows this message: "The localhost page isn’t working."

this is my browser screen short: 
[image]

Comment: make sure mod_rewrite is working

Comment: yes i can see phpinfo(); and my another cakephp project is running @pradeep